# WPF datagrid: DataGridCheckBoxColumn events

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, checkbox, datagrid

In my WPF project I have build the following `datagrid` with checkbox column:

XAML

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          TargetUpdated="IsIntermediatePointFixedByBracketDataGrid_TargetUpdated">
        <DataGrid.Columns>               
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding=
                "{Binding isFixedByBracket, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True }" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

C#

```
private void IsIntermediatePointFixedByBracketDataGrid_TargetUpdated(object sender,
    DataTransferEventArgs e)
{
    DataGrid dg = (DataGrid)sender;
    if (dg.SelectedIndex != -1 
        && ((IsFixedByBracketElement)dg.SelectedItem).isFixedByBracket
        != this.currentIntermediatePosition.isFixedByBracket[dg.SelectedIndex])
    {
        this.currentIntermediatePosition.isFixedByBracket[dg.SelectedIndex] = 
                    ((IsFixedByBracketElement)dg.SelectedItem).isFixedByBracket;
    }
}
```

When I check/uncheck a checkbox, the `TargetUpdated` event is thrown, but the value changes only if I select and deselect the cell that contains the checkbox.
Why does this happen? How can I change this behavior?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Reason for this is because the default behavior of binding inside `CellTemplates` are `UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus`.

Change to :

```
<DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding isFixedByBracket, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True ,
                        UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged }" />
```

Comment: I need to do something when a checkbox is checked. I've noticed that the event raised is the TargetUpdated event, but it is not helpful because there I have always a value 0 for the DataGrid.selectedIndex variable...and I don't understand why. Is TargetUpdated the correct event to watch?

Comment: And how can I get the correspondant row of the checkbox checked?

Comment: @FrancescoDS i don't know why selected index is zero , i'm guessing it corresponds
to the underlying CollectionView , setting IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" would probably fix that, 
but any ways check the SelectedItem of the DataGrid and then provide some indication from your ItemsSoruce , FYI iv'e never used NotifyOnTargetUpdated i copied that from the code in your question.

Comment: ItemsControl.SelectionChanged

Comment: SelectionChanged is raised each time I change cell selection...I need an event that is raised after the check of a checkbox...